# $|\{0,1\}^\infty| = |\mathbb{R}|$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers

Let $\{0,1\}^\infty$ = {$(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}; a_n \in \{0,1\} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$}

Is there a bijection between $\{0,1\}^\infty$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

I thought about something like this: If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x=a_1,a_2a_3\ldots a_na_{n+1}\ldots$, where $a_1$ is the integer part and $a_n$, $1<n$ are the decimal digits.

So, $f(x)$ would be something like $f(x)=(\underbrace{1,...,1}_{a_1 number 1},0,\underbrace{1,...1}_{a_2number1},0,...)$ .

I don't know if I made my self clear... So I'd like some help to formalize this and to know if I'm in the right way...

Thanks!

Comment: think of binary expansions of real numbers. Argue why it suffices to find a bijection from the set of sequences above to the reals satisfying $0\le x\le 1$.

Comment: If you think of binary expansions, be careful with numbers $1 = 0.111\dots$, $0.1 = 0.0111\dots$ and so on.

Comment: Your $ f $ is not a bijection: It is not defined on negative numbers and, except for perhaps the first block, all its blocks of consecutive ones are short.

Comment: Do you know the Bernstein-Cantor-Schroeder theorem? It may simplify your task. Alternatively, look up "Cantor's function".

Comment: @AndresCaicedo What if I started the sequence with a zero when x is negative? And I didn't understand what you mean by "its blocks of consecutive ones are short."... I'm not familiar with the Bernstein-Cantor-Schroeder theorem, but I will look up to it and Cantor's function...

Comment: Since $ a_2$ is a digit, the block of $ a_2$ consecutive ones can never consist of 300 ones, for instance.

Comment: @Antonie If $a_n$ is a zero, $f$ would map it to a zero, then there would be another zero to separate it from the "ones" of $a_{n+1}$. I was hoping that there was a simple bijection... :(

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Oh, you're right... So I can't "fix" $f$ so it will be a bijection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}$ into $(0,1)$, given by:
$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan x$$
and an injective map from $(0,1)$ into $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$, given by the base-$2$ representation of a real number in $(0,1)$. Since there is an injective map from $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ into a Cantor set $K\subset(0,1)$, given by:
$$\psi : \{a_n\in\{0,1\}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\to \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2a_k+1}{5^k}$$
then $\mathbb{R},(0,1)$ and $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ have the same cardinality due to the [Cantor-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem).